# How to fix image layout/positioning problem?

Tags: html, css

Minimum code to reproduce the problem:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="border: 1px solid red; width: 3px; height: 30px;">
        <img src="images1.png" style="object-fit: fill; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    </div>
    <div style="border: 1px solid blue; width: 30px;  height: 3px;">
        <img src="images1.png" style="object-fit: fill; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The bottom image is displaced downward relative to the container, although the top image is not displaced anywhere.
If the height of the bottom container is increased to 15px, then everything is displayed normally. The problem is reproducible in at least Firefox 84.0.1 x 64 and MS Edge 87.0.664.66 browsers.
Why is this happening and how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: How does it look for you? with the code snippet you provided there is literally nothing to see or reproduce. How is it intended to look like? Please add pictures showing the issue and a drawing of the intended layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image is vertically aligned with the baseline of the strut, which is determined by the font-size and line-height of the div.

The line containing the strut and the img *overflows* the div's height and since the div's overflow is set to "visible", the image is displayed below the div.

To fix, break the vertical alignment with the strut by setting

```
img {
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```css
img {
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="border: 1px solid red; width: 3px; height: 30px;">
        <img src="images1.png" style="object-fit: fill; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    </div>
    <div style="border: 1px solid blue; width: 30px;  height: 3px;">
        <img src="images1.png" style="object-fit: fill; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. It works!
But why does the div overflow, shouldn't the image have to adjust to it?
And why does everything display fine if we increase the div height to 15px?

Comment: "...shouldn't the image have to adjust to it?" No there's nothing in the CSS specs that say it should, let alone when that adjustment should be applied or what exactly that adjustment would be. By the time the div height has increased to 15px, it encompasses the baseline of the strut and the image sits entirely above it, and so inside the div.

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify the display type for img as "block".

```html
.block-img {
  display: block;
}
```

But it is not always appropriate in terms of design.